# Installshield 2012 New Language Dialogs still English even though String Table shows translations

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I am trying to add a new language to a set of Installshield installers that come together in a suite installer.

At first, the new language was not one listed in the “Tools->Add New Language…” wizard. But following the advice from [Q106687: Add an Unsupported Language to a Basic MSI Project](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/en_US/HOWTO/Q106687) and from
 kor21727 in [InstallShield Community: Adding an unsupported Language](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-182683.html) the new language appeared:

1. Modify a file `<IS Install Path>\Support\Language.dat` (add **`Azeri=42c`**)
2. Modify a file `<IS Install Path>\Support\ProLanguage.dat` (add **`Azeri=42c`**)
3. Modify a file `<IS Install Path>\Support\Langs.ini` (add **`1068=Installed`**)
4. Make a duplicate of this folder `<IS Install Path>\Redist\0409` as `<IS Install Path>\Redist\042C`
5. Make a file `<IS Install Path>\Support\0x042c.ini`
6. Make a file `<IS Install Path>\Languages\1068 (UNICODE).txt`

After doing the above I was able to add the new language to all my installers. Everything appears to be OK except when I come to the Suite installer. The other installers show the translated strings from the string table in the User Interface->Dialogs section. However, the suite installer still shows English dialogs. The suite installer builds but when I try to run it I get an unknown error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do two additional things in order to include Azeri in a Suite installation. There may also be a third thing if your use of Azeri should be right-to-left. (From some spot research it appears that Azeri is sometimes written right-to-left, and sometimes left-to-right, depending on which characters it uses. I'm uncertain whether InstallShield's Suites support this nuance, so you may have to decide up front.)

- Add a `REG_SZ` value `1068=Installed` to `HKLM\Software\InstallShield\NN.N\Professional\Languages` (this allowed me to select Azeri in the IDE; if you had used the Add New Language wizard, it may have done this for you).
- Add a `1068 (UNICODE).txt`in the `<IS Install Path>\Languages\Suite` folder. Note that the strings here are not identical to the ones in the `<IS Install Path>\Languages` folder.

After these additional changes, I was able to add Azeri to my suite project, to select it run time, and to see the strings I had changed from English appear correctly. (I did not try with actual Azeri strings; I just prefixed the English strings with `Azeri`, but outside of any font issues this shouldn't matter.)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found that the set of steps above were basically OK but that the 1068 (UNICODE).txt file I'd used was copied as a starting point was incompatible with the 1068 code page. Also I found that Azeri uses a character, the schwa - like an inverted e, that is in **no** code pages. I had to put Installshield in Unicode database mode which seems OK so far.